# PermissionError occurred when tried to access '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata/'

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm learning how to use tesseract, and I have just installed tesseract using homebrew and pytesseract using pip.
My code looks like this:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata/"

#...
```

But when I ran it, I got this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata/'
```

I'll provide further info if you need.

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to run a directory name as a command? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing these:

- Install `tesseract` by homebrew like this: `brew install tesseract`
- Create a new venv: `python -m venv yourVenvName`
- Inside the venv, run `pip install pytesseract`

You don't need to use `tesseract_cmd`, if you are using mac.
And try if you can use `tesseract` inside the venv.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/usr/local/bin/tesseract"

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("./test.jpg")))
```

I have installed tesseract with `brew install tesseract` and pytesseract in a new virtualenv with `pip install pytesseract`. My permission to the tesseract executable (`ls -la $(which tesseract`) are

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 p13rr0m  admin  39 May 26  2020 /usr/local/bin/tesseract -> ../Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/bin/tesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably occurs because `tessdata` is not executable. In the README they say as follows:

```py
import pytesseract

# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Example tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
```

The variable `tesseract_cmd` is used as follows in [this file](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/pytesseract/pytesseract.py) under the function `run_tesseract`:

```py
    cmd_args = []
...
    cmd_args += (tesseract_cmd, input_filename, output_filename_base)
...
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != ENOENT:
            raise e
        raise TesseractNotFoundError()
```

The exception is probably raised from the try-except block, because you cannot execute an unexecutable file, resulting in a permission error.

What you should do is to find the `tesseract` executable and refer to it instead of `tessdata`. As pointed out by @p13rr0m in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69217659/16699883) , it is probably located in `"/usr/local/bin/tesseract"`. In such a case you should not modify the variable `tesseract_cmd` as it is initially referring to the command `tesseract` which is already accessible from your PATH environment variable.